# .Net 4.0+WCF+WIndows Authentication + IIS

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I am trying to host my WCF service in IIS, which supports Windows Authentication. I am able to do it using Framework 3.5, but when I change the Framework to 4.0, it gives the below error.

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

I am able to host the service on development server. But we have to do it using IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="IService1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>        
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244%28WS.10%29.aspx) has information on how to enable anonymous access for IIS7.

From the UI, you need to do the following:

- Open IIS Manager, and left click on your website / application
- In the Features pane, double click in Authentication
- On the Authentication page, right click on the Anonymous Authentication item and select   enable.

Comment: I don't want to do Anonymous access. It should be based on windows authentication only. Anonymouss authentication takes away all benifits of windows authentication.

Comment: Your service requires anonymous auth because of <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>. Setting httpGetEnabled to false should remove the requirement.

Comment: Even if i keep it as false, i get the same error. Same config works with 3.5.

Comment: Hmm finally i have solved the issue.

Thanks for all your replies. But it was no where related to IIS.

I should use fully qualified name in the service name and contract. Please find the code below.

 <service name="BNP.Horizon.Service.Web.AuthenticationService">
    <endpoint name="AuthenticationService"
         address=""
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
         contract="BNP.Horizon.Service.Web.IAuthenticationService">
    </endpoint>
   </service>