# WCF Hosted on IIS6

Tags: wcf, iis

I am trying to prevent annonymous access being allowed to my WCF service however i keep getting an error message "Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."

I have tried various ideas such as removing the mex endpoint and setting the security mode as Transport credential only but this does not work.

Config:

My App pool identity is configured to a network account which sits on my domain,
My Website has Anonymous access unticked and Integrated Windows Authentication ticked. 
My Service config is:

```
<services>      
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CRMDataDashboard_Service.CoreServiceBehavior"
    name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.CoreService">
    <endpoint address="http://crmb1:8900/CoreService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CRMDataDashboard_Service.ICoreService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.ChartDataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.DataDashboardServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.CoreServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Any help with this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you using basicHttpBinding?

This answer may help:
[IIS hosted WCF-service + Windows auth in IIS + TransportCredentialOnly/Windows auth in basicHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219151/iis-hosted-wcf-service-windows-auth-in-iis-transportcredentialonly-windows-au)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150612/net-4-0wcfwindows-authentication-iis

Comment: Tried these and my setting are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a binding in the config which defines windows authentication as transport security:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx).

---

### UPDATE

You need to put the above code just under `<system.serviceModel>`. You also need to point to the binding in your config (in `bindingConfiguration` use the `BasicHttpEndpointBinding` since this is what we have defined the binding as):

```
<endpoint address="http://crmb1:8900/CoreService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CRMDataDashboard_Service.ICoreService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
  <identity>
```

Comment: Where in the config would that have to go?

Comment: I have that it as above but it is still passing the same error. - Is there anything else i need in the config i.e Integrated Security = True etc.

Comment: Put your new binding here. And read that link I sent make sure you have done it all.

Comment: Checked the link - here are my bindings    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: And my service -   <service behaviorConfiguration="CRMDataDashboard_Service.CoreServiceBehavior"
        name="CRMDataDashboard_Service.CoreService">
        <endpoint address="http://crmb1:8900/CoreService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint"
          contract="CRMDataDashboard_Service.ICoreService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>